# What is a difference between ofSeq and ofList functions?

Tags: f#

Is there a reason to prefer `ofList` function over `ofSeq` when I'm converting list to other collection type?

Comment: Can you clarify this with an example?

Comment: @GuyCoder `ofList` isn't "x to List" (that'd be `toList`), it's "List to x".

Comment: Which functions? `Array.ofList`? `Set.ofList`? `Map.ofList`? `Array.ofSeq`? `Set.ofSeq`? `Map.ofSeq`? `List.ofSeq`? `Seq.ofList`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be performance differences between each approach, you would typically expect the more specialised conversions to give better results.

To give an example, `Array.ofList` is implemented through this function (https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/37a100b7caafde0f4df5a1924c9f65f4a18277a8/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/local.fs#L300):

```
let toArray (l:'T list) =
    let len = l.Length
    let res = arrayZeroCreate len
    let rec loop i l =
        match l with
        | [] -> ()
        | h::t ->
            res.[i] <- h
            loop (i+1) t
    loop 0 l
    res
```

While `Array.ofSeq` works through `Seq.toArray` (https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/seq.fs#L1231):

```
let toArray (source : seq<'T>)  = 
    checkNonNull "source" source
    match source with 
    | :? ('T[]) as res -> (res.Clone() :?> 'T[])
    | :? ('T list) as res -> List.toArray res
    | :? ICollection<'T> as res -> 
        // Directly create an array and copy ourselves. 
        // This avoids an extra copy if using ResizeArray in fallback below.
        let arr = Array.zeroCreateUnchecked res.Count
        res.CopyTo(arr, 0)
        arr
    | _ -> 
        let res = ResizeArray<_>(source)                
        res.ToArray()
```

Notice though that, in this case, the `ofSeq` function actually checks if the supplied sequence is, in fact, and `list` and, if it is, uses the specialised conversion.

Comment: Is it than safe to prefer Seq functions for conversions (if it actually checks the type and selects the specialised conversion)? What is the best practise?

Comment: @SetyCZ It's safe to use it but I wouldn't recommend preferring it.  If you were working with custom collections, for example, you might not get these extra checks so I think it's best to get into the right habits.  Also, I think using the more specialised conversion when it's appropriate would be more idiomatic and make it easier for others to read your code at a glance.